# How to insert data of a CSV file into SQL Server db table using powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, powershell, csv, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to do this by executing PS Script from my local machine.. where DB server is remote machine.

And in the CSV file I don't have any column names specified.(only comma separated and aligned o/p).

I don't want to use `BULK INSERT`

Comment: The phrase "I don't want to use `BULK INSERT` made me sad. If you're taking options off the table please explain why.

Comment: I want to use powershell to accomplish his task..so I need help

Comment: `BULK INSERT` and PowahShell are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways I would approach this:

**BCP.exe**

SQL Server provides the command line utility [bcp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) to bulk import data.  You could simply incorporate the bcp execution into your Powershell script or window to load the csv data.
Example:

```
$loadfile = "C:\datafile\loadthis.csv"
bcp pity.dbo.foo in $loadfile -T -c -t","
```

**Using .NET**

You could also use the .NET libraries in Powershell, but this is a much trickier proposition. First, get the [Out-DataTable](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/4208a159-a52e-4b99-83d4-8048468d29dd) and [Write-DataTable](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2fdeaf8d-b164-411c-9483-99413d6053ae) scripts by Chad Miller, which will make your life much, much easier.  Then you could do the following:

```
$dt = Import-Csv -Path "C:\datafile\loadthis.csv" | Out-DataTable
Write-DataTable -ServerInstance "localhost" -Database "pity" -TableName "foo" -Data $dt
```

These and other solutions can be found in detail in [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/11/28/four-easy-ways-to-import-csv-files-to-sql-server-with-powershell.aspx).