# Insert data row wise in a SQL Table from a CSV using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, invoke-sqlcmd

So I have this particular scenario where I need to insert data from multiple `CSV` files into multiple `SQL tables`. I have come across [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539179/how-to-import-data-from-csv-in-sql-server-using-powershell), which inserts data on a row by row basis. Below is the code-snippet from the link -

```
Import-CSV .\yourcsv.csv | ForEach-Object {Invoke-Sqlcmd `
  -Database $database -ServerInstance $server `
  -Query "insert into $table VALUES ('$($_.Column1)','$($_.Column2)')"
  }
```

The problem which I am facing is, I have multiple `CSVs` with the different number of columns in them. So the option of hard-coding the code-snippet **`VALUES('$($_.Column1)','$($_.Column2)')`** doesn't exist.

Further, there are tables which contain more than 100 columns. So, writing **`VALUES('$($_.Column1)','$($_.Column2)')... so on upto '$($_.Column100)'`** is also not feasible.

What I have done for the same is stored the column names from the `CSVs` into a PowerShell array like this -

```
$File = "C:\Users\vivek.singh\Desktop\ALL_EMAILS.csv"
$csvColumnNames = (Get-Content $File | Select-Object -First 1).Split(",")
```

Now `$csvColumnNames`, has all the column names for `ALL_EMAILS` table. I am trying to fit it in the solution -

```
Import-CSV .\yourcsv.csv | ForEach-Object {Invoke-Sqlcmd `
  -Database $database -ServerInstance $server `
  -Query "insert into $table VALUES ('$($csvColumnNames[0])','$($csvColumnNames[1])',..'$($csvColumnNames[$csvColumnNames.Length])')"
  }
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I have been struggling with this for quite some time now and running out of ideas. A fresh pair of eyes will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @LotPings' solution works great. But as he suggested it might fail if records have `'` in them, which might occur in columns like `FirstName`, `LastName` etc.

Anyone looking for an alternate solution, can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405575/how-to-insert-data-of-a-csv-file-into-sql-server-db-table-using-powershell) answer. Not related to my question, but still a great way to insert data into `SQL tables` from `CSVs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Import-CSV .\yourcsv.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $AllValues = "'"+($_.Psobject.Properties.Value -join "','")+"'"
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $database -ServerInstance $server `
    -Query "insert into $table VALUES ($AllValues)"
}
```

It uses the -join operator to concatenate all values of the current row (with a leading and trailing `'` to build the `$AllValues`variable which then can be inserted into the sql command.

It's up to you to check if Csv headers match the sql column names.

To get column names once `Import-Csv`-ed you can use

```
$CSV.Psobject.Properties.Name
```

Comment: Good one indeed. Works perfectly! :)

Comment: It saves a alot of fuss dealing with an unknown column count. It might fail if there are any `'` inside column data.